# How do I embed an image into CiviMail messages?

Tags: civimail

Is possible to embedd images into civimail mailings? Would be great to have a choice between loading images from the server and sending them along with the mailing. For example Acymailing have this option. Is it possible in CiviMail?

Comment: Docs: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/everyday-tasks/#inserting-an-image-in-an-email

Answer (score 5):

If you are referring to embedding images in the body of the email, yes, that is entirely possible in CiviMail.

Using the WYSIWYG editor, you can embed images. There is an image icon on the toolbar to do this.  The images will be stored on your server and can be referenced in the HTML email.  (Of course you could optionally just include the image hosted at a different URL as well.)

You could theoretically embed the byte stream of an image, though I don't know why you would want/need this.

If you are referring to attaching the images as attachments that is possible too.  Check the Attachments section when you are defining the email in CiviMail.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed an image (rather than a link to the image) directly into an email by viewing the image in any image editor and then copying and pasting the image into the CiviCRM HTML email editor.

Doing so has several undesirable effects however:

1. The image will be stored in your database rather than as a file. If you send a lot of large pictures over a period of time, then your database may grow unreasonably large making maintenance tasks such as a daily backup more difficult.
2. Users on slow or pay-by-byte connections may be displeased.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same requirement for my organization. I want to be able to embed the image into the email body. I think you need to convert the image to Base64 encoding - see [this stack exchange post on the topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706891/embedding-image-in-html-email)